# What does " Did not find 'scent.py', running nose: " error means, while using sniffer?

Tags: python, sniffer

I am using sniffer to run the unit tests. While using sniffer I get the above mentioned error, but the unit test run as expected.

What does this error signify ?

Comment: Somebody has a bad cold?

Comment: It means someone wrote a terrible and obscure error message

Comment: look at the bottom of the source code https://github.com/jeffh/sniffer/blob/master/sniffer/runner.py

Comment: I have check the source code. Would have loved, if the author have put little information about how to use the scent.py file. I can find this scent.py file here https://github.com/Qwlouse/Findeco/blob/master/scent.py . It looks like this manages to override the default way to find tests and how to run unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

scent.py is a file to create in order to improve sniffer support to a python project

https://pypi.org/project/sniffer/

from their doc:

Don’t want to run nose? You can do whatever you really want. Create a scent.py file in your current working directory. Here’s an example of what you can do so far:
from sniffer.api import * # import the really small API
import os, termstyle

```
# you can customize the pass/fail colors like this
pass_fg_color = termstyle.green
pass_bg_color = termstyle.bg_default
fail_fg_color = termstyle.red
fail_bg_color = termstyle.bg_default

# All lists in this variable will be under surveillance for changes.
watch_paths = ['.', 'tests/']

# this gets invoked on every file that gets changed in the directory. Return
# True to invoke any runnable functions, False otherwise.
#
# This fires runnables only if files ending with .py extension and not prefixed
# with a period.
@file_validator
def py_files(filename):
    return filename.endswith('.py') and not os.path.basename(filename).startswith('.')

# This gets invoked for verification. This is ideal for running tests of some sort.
# For anything you want to get constantly reloaded, do an import in the function.
#
# sys.argv[0] and any arguments passed via -x prefix will be sent to this function as
# it's arguments. The function should return logically True if the validation passed
# and logicially False if it fails.
#
# This example simply runs nose.
@runnable
def execute_nose(*args):
    import nose
    return nose.run(argv=list(args))
```